# Apt-get is going mental when trying to install C++

Tags: c++, installation, apt-get, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to use 'apt-get install c++' to install C++ onto my Ubuntu 14.04 machine but it just seems to go crazy and it also does this when I try to install any other package also.  I captured the output of the command, http://pastebin.com/XFftmAmc.

Does anyone know what's going on?

-- EDIT --

This only happens with C++ and I need to install it. :/

-- EDIT --

I know what was wrong, I tried to install "c++" but the package is "g++"

Comment: Looks the package is for a newer system than yours ...

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu with the latest updates as of last night.